# Dynamic SOQL - Multiple variables

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-soql

I would like to pass two variables to my SOQL Where clause.  Can someone give me an example how this is done in Apex.  My objects are custom objects.

Variable1
Variable2

Example in SQL:

```
'Select Id, FirstName, Lastname from Object1 where FirstName like ' & Variable1 & ' OR Lastname Like ' & Variable2 & ';'
```

Thanks

Comment: Closing as a dupe, it's the same format for two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how this works with wildcard, but you can do something like the following to get dynamic soql & variable binding.

```
String filterOne = 'foo';
String filterTwo = 'bar';

String soql = 'Select Id, Name FROM Whatever__c Where a = :filterOne AND b =:filterTwo';

SObject[] obj = Database.query(soql);
```

Comment: Just add `String filterOnePlusWildcard = '%' + filterOne;`, and then use that in your SOQL dynamic binding.  Dynamic bindings getting the added bonus of being automatically protected against SOQL injection by escaping single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
SObject[] obj = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM SObjectName WHERE Name LIKE' + '%' + Variable1 + '%');
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew it should be simple but I wasn't able to find an example online.  Thanks again.

Comment: Don't forget to use escape single quotes on those variables if they come from any user input.